# Scancode map required

Tags: windows, keyboard, scancodes

I would like to disable the following-
Application.SendKeys "{1068}"

For this I'll have to disable it by adding a registry entry. I have added registry entry to disable printscreen but that does not disable this piece of code.

Any help about finding scancode map of this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the scancode map of this is '0'. As it is '0', it cannot be used in registry entry to disable the key.

Hope it helps someone else.